# How would I delete rows with employee_id under certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe called employee_change. This contains many rows and many columns. I want to iterate through the rows and every time it comes across the conditions in the if statements below I want to delete every row with the same employee id as that row

Below is the loop of every row I have

```py
for index, churned in employee_change.iterrows():
    if (churned['stopped_at'] == churned['stopped_at']) and (churned['type_of_termination'] == 'resignation') and (churned['created_at'] <= pd.Timestamp.now() - pd.DateOffset(months=3)):
        employee_change_ThreeMonths = employee_change[~churned['employee_id']]
    elif (churned['stopped_at'] != churned['stopped_at']) and (churned['type_of_termination'] == 'resignation') and (churned['created_at'] <= churned['stopped_at'] - pd.DateOffset(months=3)):
        employee_change_ThreeMonths = employee_change[~employee_id[churned['employee_id']]]
```

The conditions should be good but it is giving me the KeyError of -18736

Comment: dont use iterrows for this, you can create a sample dataframe and expected dataframe according the conditions and we will be able to help better

Comment: Look at using [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html#pandas-dataframe-duplicated) or [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-dataframe-drop-duplicates).

Comment: Use conditional slicing of data frames using `loc` and `conditions`

Comment: and what does `churned['stopped_at'] == churned['stopped_at']` mean? @Loyal_Burrito

Comment: Sorry bad question! I'll take it down. I ended up scratching this way and doing a completely new method that works perfectly. Thanks for helping though!